# What's the difference between table.insert(t, i) and t[#t+1] = i?

Tags: lua, lua-table

In Lua, there seem to be two ways of appending an element to an array:

```
table.insert(t, i)
```

and

```
t[#t+1] = i
```

Which should I use, and why?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Which to use is a matter of preference and circumstance: as the `#` length operator was introduced in version 5.1, `t[#t+1] = i` will not work in Lua 5.0, whereas `table.insert` has been present since 5.0 and will work in both. On the other hand, `t[#t+1] = i` uses exclusively language-level operators, wheras `table.insert` involves a function (which has a slight amount of overhead to look up and call and depends on the `table` module in the environment).

In the second edition of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/) (an update of the Lua 5.0-oriented first edition), Roberto Ierusalimschy (the designer of Lua) states that he prefers `t[#t+1] = i`, as it's more visible.

---

Also, depending on your use case, the answer may be "neither". See [the manual entry on the behavior of the length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5):

> If the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

As such, if you're dealing with an array with holes, using either one ([`table.insert` uses the length operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.insert)) may "append" your value to a lower index in the array than you want. How you define the size of your array in this scenario is up to you, and, again, depends on preference and circumstance: you can use `table.maxn` (disappearing in 5.2 but trivial to write), you can keep an `n` field in the table and update it when necessary, you can wrap the table in a metatable, or you could use another solution that better fits your situation (in a loop, a `local tsize` in the scope immediately outside the loop will often suffice).

Comment: My suggestion for Lua 5.3 is to add vector array construction operator [ ] like mixed array construction operator { }. This new operator will have `maxn` and `size`  fields internally, where `maxn` will be accessible through `#` length operator and `size` through `array.size(t)` or `t:size()`.

Comment: @happy_marmoset: If you need that behavior, you can implement it with what already exists in 5.2 (just set a metatable that adds those properties).

Answer (score 6):

The following is slightly on the amusing side but possibly with a grain of aesthetics. Even though there are obvious reasons that `mytable:operation()` is not supplied like `mystring:operation()`, one can easily roll one's own variant, and get a third notation if desired.

```
Table = {}
Table.__index = table                     

function Table.new()
   local t = {}
   setmetatable(t, Table)
   return t
end

mytable = Table.new()
mytable:insert('Hello')
mytable:insert('World')
for _, s in ipairs(mytable) do
   print(s)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not so obvious to me. Is it a performance consideration? Or backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

`insert` can insert arbitrarily (as its name states), it only defaults to `#t + 1`, where as `t[#t + 1] = i` will always append to the (end of the) table. see section 5.5 in [the lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that insert can take extra arguments. My question is why I would use the two argument version over `t[#t + 1] = i`

Comment: @Eric: If your variable is not named t, but myVeryDescriptiveLongNameOfMyGloballyVisibleArray then it saves keystrokes :-)

Comment: `(function(t) t[#t+1] = i end)(myVeryDescriptiveLongNameOfMyGloballyVisibleArray)`

Answer (score 1):

'#' operator only use indexed key table.

```
t = {1, 2 ,3 ,4, 5, x=1, y=2}
```

at above code

```
print(#t)  --> print 5 not 7
```

'#' operator whenever not using.

If you want to '#' operator, then check it to table elements type.

Insert function can using any type use.But element count to work slow than '#'