# How to remove a string from a table

Tags: string, lua, lua-table, computercraft

I've been trying to find a way to remove a string from a table kind of like this:

```
myTable = {'string1', 'string2'}
table.remove(myTable, 'string1')
```

but I haven't been able to find anyway to do it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

As hjpotter92 said, `table.remove` expects the position you want removed and not the value so you will have to search. The function below searches for the position of value and uses `table.remove` to ensure that the table will remain a valid sequence.

```
function removeFirst(tbl, val)
  for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
    if v == val then
      return table.remove(tbl, i)
    end
  end
end

removeFirst(myTable, 'string1')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394841/safely-remove-items-from-an-array-table-while-iterating#comment16660887_12397742

Comment: This is `removeFirst` and for that there is no better way, this is linear time. lhf's answer is for a linear time `removeAll`, which could be updated to use `table.move`

Answer (score 2):

[`table.remove` accepts](http://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-table.remove) the position of an element as its second argument. If you're sure that `string1` appears at the first index/position; you can use:

```
table.remove(myTable, 1)
```

alternatively, you have to use a loop:

```
for k, v in pairs(myTable) do -- ipairs can also be used instead of pairs
    if v == 'string1' then
        myTable[k] = nil
        break
    end
end
```