# After reading this answer i understand the benefits but am confused about the function

Tags: arrays, lua

I am looking to remove an item from a table using lua

a quick search led me to read that table.remove() is a bad idea due to efficiency

however i'm not 100% understanding the custom function

here is the function

```
function ArrayRemove(t, fnKeep)
local j, n = 1, #t;

for i=1,n do
    if (fnKeep(t, i, j)) then
        -- Move i's kept value to j's position, if it's not already there.
        if (i ~= j) then
            t[j] = t[i];
            t[i] = nil;
        end
        j = j + 1; -- Increment position of where we'll place the next kept value.
    else
        t[i] = nil;
    end
end

return t;
end
```

i understand the idea that we move the items and remove all in one loop rather than the table.remove() having to move everything ( there is a long answer here about it, [Safely remove items from an array table while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394841/safely-remove-items-from-an-array-table-while-iterating))

looking at the function above, what would happen if the item to delete is the first item?

if we replace the line `if (fnKeep(t, i, j)) then` as suggested with `(t[i] == 'deleteme')`

then nothing happens as both i and j are 1

also if the first 'if' is false then the item is removed anyways?

can someone shed some light on this for me please

**edit**

I believe the working function would be as follows

```
local j, n = 1, #t -- t is table to iterate over

for i = 1, n do -- begin the loop

    if t[i] ~= 'object to delete' then -- if this is NOT the item to remove 

        if i ~= j then -- can it be moved to new position

            t[j] = t[i] -- move to new pos
            t[i] = nil -- clear old pos

        end

        j = j + 1 -- increment the new pos counter

        end

    else -- if it is the item TO delete then delete it

    t[i] = nil

end
```

Comment: I believe that is a mistype, in the section the user titled `Bonus (Advanced Users)` they show this line for the if statement `if (v['name'] == 'Rick') then -- Keep "Rick".` The line with the if statement should be for what you want to `keep` not delete, the else statement handles values that are just deleted.

Comment: thanks, that makes far more sense, i'll add an edit to my question for anybody else who happens to be looking